# Adding Audio Controls in iOS App using Swift in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have added background music to my app using the following code:-
Now I am trying to add audio controls to my app using the following methods, but after I click on another view controller and come back to the main view controller the play button is not working. Any help will be highly appreciated Thanks!

```
var toggleState = 1
var music: AVAudioPlayer!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    playMusic()

}

func playMusic() {
    if let musicURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Adding", withExtension: "mp3") {
        if let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicURL) {
            music = audioPlayer
            music.numberOfLoops = -1
            music.play()
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if (toggleState == 1) {
        
        music.pause()
        
        toggleState = 2
        
    }
    else {
        
        music.play()
        
        toggleState = 1
        
    }

    
}
```